# Modernizr just for one quick check?

Tags: javascript, html, placeholder, modernizr

I want to check if the browser who's running my page 
is capable of handling the 'html 5 placeholder'

I know I can add the following javascript check:

```
!Modernizr.input.placeholder
```

but is it worth to import a library just for one check ?

also how does modernizr do that for me (i mean how is it implemented under the cover) ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to check for `placeholder` support, then all you need to do is;

```
var placeholderSupport = "placeholder" in document.createElement("input");
```

And to answer your other question; **no**, there is absolutely no point including the whole Modernizr library for 1 line of JS (Modernizr is 1000+ lines.... go figure :))*

<sup><sup>*Yes, not minified, but the concept remains</sup></sup>

Comment: A point of clarification, Modernizr provides the uncompressed source for research and development purposes. Modernizr offers no minified version with everything in it. You are encouraged to create a custom build. So it's not a oneliner vs 1000+ liner comparison.

Comment: Additionally Modernizr is a repository of edge cases. Testing support for input type=range, for example, is fraught with peril. Inventing custom tests each time is a good way to end up with something as fragile as a UA sniff. People have done it before with HTML5 form input tests and all their "so simple" detects are now broken. Disclaimer: I write Modernizr, obviously. :p

Comment: To be fair, After gzip its a 87 to 500 byte difference :)

Answer (score 7):

You could just get what you need from modernizr by just selecting "Input Attributes" for example and generate a build

http://www.modernizr.com/download/

Answer (score 3):

[It's open-source.  Go read it.](http://www.modernizr.com/downloads/modernizr-2.0.6.js)

```
Modernizr['input'] = (function( props ) {
  for ( var i = 0, len = props.length; i < len; i++ ) {
    attrs[ props[i] ] = !!(props[i] in inputElem);
  }
  return attrs;
})(('autocomplete autofocus list placeholder max min ' +
    'multiple pattern required step').split(' '));
```

Comment: Admittedly, that source is very hard to understand for people who aren't familiar with that trick.

Comment: One might scratch one's head if one hasn't seen the `!!` idiom before, but it's easy to get the gist of it, which is that modernizr is just checking to see if the property exists and nothing further.

Comment: @mquander That source code is a bit beyond me. Why the two exclamation points ???

Comment: @lorenzo: It's a terse way to coerce a truthy or falsy Javascript value into being actually true or false.  For example, if `props[i]` is `42`, then `!props[i]` is `false`, so `!!props[i]` is `true`.

Comment: @mquander: Although in which circumstances is `x in y` non boolean? Doesn't it always return a boolean?

Comment: @Matt: I actually have no idea -- if you had asked me five minutes ago, I would have guessed that `in` always returns a boolean (but I've only been programming Javascript for two months.)  Hypothesis: maybe it's a way to clean up after some old browser which returns other values from `in`?

Comment: @mquander: I've never heard of `in` not returning a boolean, so I'll have to agree with your hypothesis :P

Comment: That `!!` is indeed mysterious, given the `in`.

Answer (score 1):

Found this: http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder

Code:

```
function hasPlaceholderSupport() {
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  return ('placeholder' in input);
}
```

There's also a fallback solution, by clicking the link