# How to get my html5 feature incompatibility warning to work using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I've added a form to my webpage which allows for multiple file uploads. I added the input `<input type="file" name="photo_upload[]" id="photo_upload" multiple="multiple" />`.

I've tried to add a warning which is only visible if the browser does not support the multiple file feature. I tried this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var testrange=document.createElement("input")
testrange.setAttribute("multiple", "multiple")
if (testrange.multiple=="multiple"){
    document.getElementById('multiple_warning').style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
<div id="multiple_warning" style="background:#FFFF99; border:dashed; border-width:thin;">Sorry, but your browser does not support the multiple file upload feature.<br />
If you have more than one photo to send us, please send it after you recieved your comformation email.</div>
```

but it always displays the "multiple_warning" regardless. How can I get this to behave properly?

Comment: You can use the MODERNIZR Library like in this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8010122/modernizr-just-for-one-quick-check)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the console to see why your test always failes ;)

```
testrange.setAttribute("multiple", "multiple")
console.log(testrange.multiple);
```

You could check this feature with this snippet

```
if (!("multiple" in testrange)) {
    alert("no multiple upload supported");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Modernizr to test for particular attribute. Its an open source, cross browser html 5 detection library

```
if(Modernizr.input[attribute])){
    alert("Attribute exists");
}
else{
    //error handling
}
```

See here http://modernizr.com/docs/#input

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead of the JavaScript you have:

```
var testrange = document.createElement("input")
if ("multiple" in testrange) {
    document.getElementById("multiple_warning").style.display = "none";
}
```

If you're doing a lot of feature detection, consider using [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to test these sorts of things rather than creating your own tests. It accounts for a lot of corner cases and will save you a lot of headaches.